# Changing a default color in curses

Tags: ncurses, curses, xterm

In playing with the curses library, I discovered that if a default color is changed (say COLOR_BLUE, for example) using init_color, that changed color will continue to be used across stopping and restarting my program if I don't reset it back to its original definition. Even creating a new terminal window in which to run the program, the color of blue shows up as defined in the original windows. It even survives running a completely different program.

How is this happening? I would have thought the original definition would be used upon starting a new instance. I can only surmise that these default colors are cached somewhere at the OS level. Can someone explain what is happening here that allows this to happen?

I'm running this on a Centos 7.6 distro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colors are maintained/cached/whatever by a given terminal.

If the [terminal description](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html#h3-Predefined-Capabilities) has this feature:

```
      orig_colors                 oc        oc     Set all color pairs
                                                   to the original ones
```

that would be sent by the ncurses library as part of [exiting curses mode](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/797233319c7e74e0d00839795e787530ee1c1cee/ncurses/tty/tty_update.c#L2244).

It also ***might*** be sent by [`reset`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tset.1.html#h3-reset---reinitialization) (or [`tput reset`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html#h3-Commands)) command as part of the `rs1` string.  That's not automatic (and those commands do nothing special with color other than as a side-effect of the initialization and reset strings).

xterm supports a control sequence for resetting palettes back to their default, which was added to the terminal description in

> [`2016-04-23`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#t20160423)
> `#       + add 'oc' capability to xterm+256color, allowing palette reset for`
> `#         xterm -TD`

referring to this:

```
oc=\E]104\007,
```

That uses OSC 104, which was developed for xterm in [patch #252](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_252) (2009/12/7):

> add OSC 104, for resetting ANSI/16/88/256 colors to default.

However, in discussing CentOS (RHEL), you have to keep in mind that it doesn't get updates for things like that:

- The package information says that it has a development snapshot of ncurses from just a couple of days past [8 years ago](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#t20130511).
- Your terminal may/may not support the control sequence.  If you are using xterm, no problem.  For anything else (with that version of CentOS), you are out of luck.  VTE developers (e.g., gnome-terminal) copied the feature in [January 2014](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vte/-/commit/f957cd94c3057965bc8d74d0811252ff9dbb9894), but ***that*** version of VTE was released as 0.35.2, while CentOS 7 has 0.28.2

Comment: Very detailed response! Not sure I grasp it all but it appears that I'm basically screwed. Yeah?

Comment: If the terminal supports `\E]104\007`, you could modify the terminal database using `tic`, but if not, you'd also have to upgrade the terminal and supporting libraries (usually not simple).